# which IP will be called if /etc/hosts has entry 0.0.0.0/0 for load balancer

Tags: dns, hosts-file, internal-load-balancer

Load balancer for our application myloadbalancer.myorg.net returns either of the active  IP ( 165.a.b.c or  165.x.y.z ). If we keep an entry in /etc/hosts file for  load balancer like below

```
0.0.0.0/0      myloadbalancer.myorg.net     alias_name
```

will load balancer still work in same way as it is working now and will return  active  IP ?

Can i also provide entry like below

```
165.0.0.0/32     myloadbalancer.myorg.net   alias_name
```

Which will work more efficiently ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have only single IP address in /etc/hosts entry, not the network. Your first example `0.0.0.0/0` denotes the whole Internet, and `165.0.0.0/32` makes no sense.

Comment: Does that mean  entry =>  0.0.0.0/0      myloadbalancer.myorg.net     alias_name  will work . The default   IP out of whole network will be returned  ?

Comment: The 2nd entry represents  CIDR classless IP addressing  .

Comment: length /32 means 1 host.

Comment: 165.0.0.0/2     myloadbalancer.myorg.net   alias_name Will this entry work ?

Comment: No. __You can have only a single IP address in /etc/hosts entry, not the network__.  Also `165.0.0.0/2` represents a network of  1073741822 IP addresses in a range `128.0.0.1 - 165.255.255.254`